# Simple mod_rewrite producing unexpected redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite

Well I've driven myself crazy enough that I finally had to break down and ask for some help.

I have a simple rewrite rule in my .htaccess file in a folder called "myfolder"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

If the url is /myfolder/home

In the index.php file located in "myfolder" I simply call

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])){$page = $_GET['page'];}else{$page = 'home';}
//then I include the content for requested page using
include('pages/'.$page.'/content.php');
```

//NOTE: I have checks to see if the page exists in the final code, but for now I am keeping it simple trying to track down this issue

If I print_r($_GET); It shows Array ( [page] => home )

So it works as expected and the page content loads, but if I look in the browser error console I see a php error and when I click on the error I see Array ( [page] => df )
**Warning**:  require(pages/df/content):

For some reason it's thinking that page = df and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Does it have to do with a rewrite loop or something?

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured it out.  I had a page.js file I was including that I thought was blank (long story why I'm including it) but it actually had "df" in it.  I guess the combination of the file being named page.js and garbage javascript caused all kinds of havoc.

Oh the joys of coding never cease do they haha.

Thanks anyway guys.

PS I'll make this answered after the two day limit is up.